# how to install python3.5 completely and remove python2.7 on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I have installed python3.5 with commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

after

```
pip install matplotlib 
pip install numpy
pip install scikit-learn
```

It works but only on python2.7.6 installed by default. When I type "python",it show me the interactive shell of python2.7.6. I can use python3.5 by type "python3",but i can't import some library i install such as numpy, scikit-learn, matplotlib but it works in 2.7.6.

How to use all my libraries i install with python3.5 instead of 2.7.6?

Comment: ummm... how are you using `apt-get` on a Mac?

Comment: just like on Linux " sudo apt-get install..." or " sudo apt-get update"...

Comment: Mac doesn't come with `apt-get`, "advanced packaging tool" is an ubuntu technology. But generally if you have installed python 3 on the mac then you can access it using `python3`, and you need to make sure you have installed pip into python 3 then `pip3` will install the packages to the right version. You may also want to look into `virtualenv`s, e.g. `python3 -m venv`

Comment: Nice, let me do it and give you guys the feedBack

Answer (score 1):

`pip3` will ensure you're installing packages for `python3` if there's confusion with a Python 2.x installed on the same machine.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks for adding this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the best way to deal with it i think. I download Anaconda from this link (https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Anaconda integrates many academic libraries by default so I choose to download anaconda with the Python 3 version and all libraries going with. So now I can use it in PyCharm.

[image]

So creating a new project, I just have to choose the rep of python in my anaconda folder.

Thanks guys.